# Class does not implement org.graalvm.nativeimage.hosted.Feature error of Quarkus project with GraalVM native-image

Tags: java, quarkus, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I'm trying to compile sample [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/) project to native image using GraalVM and Maven. Here is the code of my Quarkus service:

```
package gk.testquarkus;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

When I compile it as usual java app with `mvn package` all goes well. But whe I try to compile it to the native image with `mvn package -Pnative` I get such error:

> Error: Class does not implement
>   org.graalvm.nativeimage.hosted.Feature: io.quarkus.runner.AutoFeature

What's the reason and how can I fix that? I use GraalVM 19.1.1 and Quarkus  0.13.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upgrade to Quarkus 0.20.0: [changelog saying it works with GraalVM 19.1.1](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/releases/tag/0.20.0).